# Special solution of following system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Suppose now system of differential equations, namely,
$$
\begin{equation} \ddot{y}(t) + \omega^{2}y(t) = \dot{z}(t) \\ \dot{z}(t) = (-A+\dot{y}(t))z(t)\end{equation}
$$
I want to check, for which $y(t)$ the second derivative $\ddot{y}$ is zero. Combining the first and the second equations, I obtain following differential equation:
$$
(-A+\dot{y}(t))z(t) - \omega^{2}y(t) = 0
$$
The question: may I divide on $z(t)\neq 0$, and after that differentiate obtained equation with respect to $t$, again setting $\ddot{y}$ to zero?

This question arises, because if I don't divide on $z(t)$, then the equation on $\dot{y}(t)$ will look differently after derivating with respect to $t$, and I don't understand, why.

Comment: You ask: "which $y(t)$  the second derivative $\ddot{y}(t)$   is zero ? ". Elementary calculus answers to this question : $y(t)=c_1t+c_2$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants. Bringing $y(t)=c_1t+c_2$ into the two differential equations leads to $c_1=c_2=0 \quad\to\quad z(t)=y(t)=0$. By the way, you have not to divide by $z(t)$ to get the answer to your question: "which $y(t)$  the second derivative $\ddot{y}(t)$   is zero ? ". But why do you think that $\ddot{y}(t)=0$ ?

Comment: @JJacquelin : I'm looking for approximate solutions, when $\ddot{y} =\dot{z} = 0$, i.e., looking for the bound for $\omega$ parameter, for which I can neglect the term $\omega^{2}\theta$.

Comment: You have to understand that when $y''=z'=0$ the solution is $y(t)=z(t)=0$ as said in my first comment. I suppose that it isn't what you expect. This is because you add a condition $=0$. Without this condition, in the case $y''=z'\neq 0$ the solution is no longer trivial. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for approximate solution [according to your comment] in the case  $\omega=0$ see the solution below :

[image]

$c_1$ , $c_2$ , $c_3$ are constants.